# CROSS JOIN with one empty table sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have two tables say `MyFull` and `MyEmpty`. I need to do the combination of all records from both tables. Sometimes, `MyEmpty` table might have no records, in this scenario I need to return all records from `MyFull`. This is what I have tried:

```
 --Q1 >> returns no results
 SELECT *
 FROM MyFull CROSS JOIN MyEmpty 

--Q2 >> returns no results 
SELECT *
FROM MyFull, MyEmpty
```

I though of using `LEFT JOIN` but I have no common key to join on. This is a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4a6c7/2/0)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyFull
LEFT JOIN MyEmpty ON 1=1
```

Though be aware that if you have multiple records in `MyEmpty`, it will repeat records from `MyFull` once for every record in `MyEmpty`. Effectively, the number of records in the results is MyFull * MyEmpty (unless MyEmpty has no records).

Comment: Thanks Joel. This is what I am looking for. I want to repeat records actually.

Answer (score 6):

Full table :

```
declare @t table (Spot int,name varchar(1),pct int)
insert into @t(Spot,name,pct)values(1,'A',2),(1,'B',8),(1,'C',6),(2,'A',4),(2,'B',5),(3,'A',5),(3,'D',1),(3,'E',4)
```

Empty table :

```
declare @tt table (Spot int,name varchar(1),pct int)
select * from @t OUTER APPLY @tt
```

Comment: what ever joel's solution fetching the result set outer apply doing the same@Ala

Comment: `SELECT * FROM MyFull OUTER APPLY MyEmpty` seems pretty intuitive too.  Same execution plan too im sure.